# How should you hook a session_start() when authoring a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, session

Learning more about sessions I've gathered that a `session_start()` should come directly after `<?php` per [Where exactly do I put a SESSION_START?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308478/where-exactly-do-i-put-a-session-start) and I wanted to play around and create a plugin that would add a `session_start()` to `header.php` after it's `<?php` but after searching I've been inclusive with trying to figure out the appropriate procedure to do this.

I did search for [session](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=session) but I've seen a variety of Q&As that mostly seem to use:

- `init`: [Session is not starting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149132/session-is-not-starting)
- `wp_head`: [Hook into wp_head(); in a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167928/hook-into-wp-head-in-a-plugin)
- `wp_loaded`: [Getting headers already sent error from plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105453/getting-headers-already-sent-error-from-plugin)

So when authoring a plugin that relies on session to be added to header.php what is the appropriate hook for adding `session_start()`?

Comment: Just some [food for thought](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/168089/7355) regarding sessions. Some say you should [add it into config](http://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/).

Comment: really?  I've never heard of that before.  Isn't it bad for a plugin to modify the config?  That may lead to another question after searching.

Comment: actually, you would only start a session if it's not started already. `if ( !session_id() ) { session_start(); }` so I don't think it's really important but it should definitely be checked before you need to use the $_SESSION. But I'm curious if someone has a better explanation

Comment: @bynicolas yes I am aware of that but I was more interested in where to target the session for it's placement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no regular output and hence no header sent before `template_redirect` on the front end. If you need sessions on the back end too, use the action `wp_loaded` to cover both.

Example:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    $status = session_status();

    if ( PHP_SESSION_DISABLED === $status ) {
        // That's why you cannot rely on sessions!
        return;
    }

    if ( PHP_SESSION_NONE === $status ) {
        session_start();
    }

    $_SESSION[ 'foo' ] = 'bar';
});
```

Keep in mind that using sessions adds a whole [set of very complex problems](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167585/73) to your code, including security, scalability (load balancers), and following time consuming support issues. I don't recommend it.

Comment: Ok, if session is bad I suppose I will look at PHP's 'set_cookie()'.  I would assume the same approach would apply as you have here, to use 'template_redirect' or 'wp_loaded'?

Comment: I found this little document insightful at least as far as issues with sessions in WP: https://pressjitsu.com/blog/wordpress-sessions-performance/

Answer (score 1):

Here is also another solution for all kind of PHP versions what you can find inside [CF Geo Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-geoplugin/):

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0') >= 0) {
    if(function_exists('session_status') && session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start(array(
          'cache_limiter' => 'private_no_expire',
          'read_and_close' => false,
       ));
    }
}
else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') >= 0)
{
    if (function_exists('session_status') && session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
        session_start();
    }
}
else
{
    if(session_id() == '') {
        if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '4.0.0') >= 0){
            session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
        }
        session_start();
    }
}
```

With this solution you can prevent any problem with session and start it anytime you need.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the easy way by init hook. Write this function in the function.php

```
function register_my_session() {
  if( !session_id() )
  session_start();
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

after adding this function in function.php you can Set values in sessions like

```
$_SESSION['user_country'] = 'india';
```

Get session value

```
echo $_SESSION['user_country'];
```

for destroying session value

```
unset($_SESSION["user_country"]);
```

Comment: You should escape session values before you print them out.