# Using sessions or an alternative in a plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, session

I want to use sessions in a plugin, I use this code in my plugin to start a session

```php
add_action('init','register_session',1);
function register_session(){
    global $cons;
    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
    if (isset($_GET['abc'])){
        $_SESSION['abcd'] = $_GET['abc'];
    }
}
```

The session variable works even after a page reload where the GET is not set but then the session seams to be destroyed.
I am also geting this warning from my plugin php file

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in
```

Is there an alternative way to store session data or make sessions work? I have seen some plugins but I would prefer to not use them.
Also I have seen this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237023/how-should-you-hook-a-session-start-when-authoring-a-plugin) and it doen't work for me

**EDIT:**
The session seems to be active always but the session variable is reseted after 2 different page loads

Comment: You mean fuxia's template_redirect answer? You really shouldn't be getting 'headers already sent' then. What's the code in the warning that's sent output before that?

Comment: It's just the same warning from previous page loads

Comment: And that's the complete text of the warning "Cannot start session when headers already sent in" ? It doesn't give you a filename and a line e.g. /wp-content/plugins/something/ or /wp-content/themes/ that you can use to work out where the first output is? I suppose you could pick an earlier hook instead.

Comment: Yes there is a path to my plugin after the warning, the  path is /home/497655.cloudwaysapps.com/emgkpuhbhv/public_html/wp-content/plugins/lw-for-woocommerce/wc-lw.php on line 22 . What is an earlier hook than init?

Comment: I can't find that plugin to see what it's doing, I guess it's not public. If you said you've already tried template_redirect instead of init and that didn't fix it, then I guess you could try after_setup_theme or even plugins_loaded, but I'd look at your lw-for-woocommerce plugin and work out what the action handler is on line 22 of that file and what it's doing: it really ought not be outputting anything before template_redirect, and that feels like the right one to use to me.

Comment: This is my plugin and line 22 is the session_start(); line in the code I have attached

Comment: Oh. I meant the line it tells you that already sent the headers. It should be something like "headers already sent by (output started at /wp-content/plugins/some-other-plugin.php:123". That's the place to look.